# INDEX MATCH not returning data correctly

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, matching

I have an Index/match and it isn't returning all names correctly. The error seems to be if there is a duplicate last name but I don't know how to correct it. Here is my formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('[Data File]Sheet1'!$E:$E, MATCH(A2, '[Data File]Sheet1'!$B:$B & "," & '[Data File]Sheet1'!$C:$C, 0)), "")`

The idea is to return a blank unless what is input in column A matches the data from Data File Sheet1. Data File Sheet1 Column B is Last names and Column C is first names. I have no control over this file.

My file logs names as first, last in column A. When sucessful this should return the matching line E from Data File Sheet1.

Like I said, this seems to work if the last name is unique but breaks if there is a duplicate.

The first image is what the data is input like in my program.
The second is what the data looks like in the sheet I pull data from.

[image: Column A is the First name, Last name]

[image: Data File Sheet1 lists names as column B last name column C first name]

In these images only Fake Name would work with my code, Should Work and Might Work will both return my error line, i.e. a blank.

Comment: Difficult to provide advice without seeing sample data. In `MATCH`you are concatenating `B` and `C` columns, but we don´t know what is in `A2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Key column for your name match to avoid this. You can use a concat of the first and last name to get better matches.

Enter this into your new column =(*Firstnamecell*&" "*Lastnamecell*)
Use this key column in your formula Match(A2, *referenceyourKeyColumn*, 0))

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple and effective solution.